# How to evenly distribute nodes in graph?

Tags: graph

I am building a graph .
As I might add/remove nodes I want to create graph where it is balanced means each node will have average same number of connection. So that nodes are evenly distributed .

So suppose I create  1,2,3,4 to graph

it should be connected like say

```
1 - 2 - 4
    |
     _ 3
```

Here average **degree is 2** .

instead of

```
1-2-3-4
```

Here average **degree is 1**.

Max depth of graph must be lon2(N)

N is total number of nodes .

Comment: Can you provide an example?  There are many kinds of graphs, and many definitions of "evenly distributed".

Comment: You need to define a proper metric of what is "balanced" before trying to achieve it.